# Mysql JDBC getTimestamp returns wrong value

Tags: mysql, jdbc, timestamp

Mysql JDBC getTimestamp returns wrong value.

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

mysql> select @@time_zone;
+-------------+
| @@time_zone |
+-------------+
| +00:00      |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select id,time from Foo;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | time                       |
+----+----------------------------+
|  9 | 2021-03-28 08:00:00.000000 |
+----+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

JDBC:

```
java.sql.Timestamp value = resultSet.getTimestamp(2);
```

The returned value is:

```
2021-03-28T00:00:00.000-0400
```

It should be:

```
2021-03-28T04:00:00.000-0400
```

MySql JDBC: 6.0.6. Its source code available for debugging? Could not find it.

### UPDATE

For a small test case, it gets correct value, which uses the same Mysql database, same column type timestamp, and same JDBC driver. What might be the cause? This issue occurred suddenly. For the test automation, no issues until today.

Comment: Do not use MySQL Connector/J 6.0.6. It is a development version. Use a MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x version. Also please show how you print the value, because the `toString()` of a `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't produce that output.

Comment: Check the mysql session (or default) timezone.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, the string value is from debugger (intellij).

Comment: @Vatev,  It does not matter what is the mysql session timezone because the string value has zone info.

Comment: What if you use "modern" LocalDateTime instead? `java.sql.Timestamp` is somewhat outdated.

Comment: LocalDateTime: is local time, without zone info.

Comment: `java.sql.Timestamp` does not have a time zone either. If you really need time zone information use `java.time.ZonedDateTime` or `java.time.OffsetDateTime`  (but MySQL's `timestamp` does not have any time zone information either)

Comment: TImestamp is UTC time, and it can be converted to the time of any time zone. It is legacy code. Do not want to change to java.time now.